# Exclude a dll dependency file out of deployment VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, deployment, publish

I'm building a net core 6 project using Visual Studio 2022 to run on a Linux container. When I build my project for deployment it includes all these files to run on Windows which I do not need. They are part of the system.data.sqlclient. I only need these for Linux. How do I tell VS 2022 to exclude them?